# AWS multi account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have an AWS account that works well with tens of activated features and working in production.
For testing & development purposes I would love to have a *separate* account not connected to the first one at all. Even with another credit card attached.

So my question is: is there any possible way to use single e-mail & password to access both account and then switch somehow between them in management console? Or is the only way to register additional e-mail?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to register another account. you can setup consolidated billing to only have to worry about paying for just one of them.

Comment: In order to _register another account_ I should use another e-mail?

Comment: yes use another email or if your email is user@domain.com you could use the same email but do something like user+aws2@domain.com

Comment: You can also switch back & forth between accounts in the console easily using cross-account roles. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-account-access-in-the-aws-management-console/.

Comment: @jarmod this pretty awesome. did not know about this feature.